# How can I connect my NodeJS/Express backend to my VueJS frontend using only one port on my local machine?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, development-environment, production-environment

My Vue app is set up using Vue CLI (Webpack) and it's working as it should. My NodeJS/Express REST API is also working properly. However, to run them simultaneously I now start a local server for each of them -- each with its own port. I would like to have both of them communicate over one port.

Localhost:8080 should point to the home page of my Vue App and the API requests should follow localhost:8080/api/...

In my production environment I use one and the same port/URL by serving the Vue App as a set of static files ('dist' folder). In my development environment I don't know how to set this up, however.

I looked around for answers online, but feel lost among all the different terms I have come across (.env, crossenv, nginx, cors) and that I am running in circles.

What would be a good way of setting this up?

Thank you

Edit:

I ended up creating three modes to run my application:

1. Development
   I use one script in a package.json to start the frontend and backend server on different ports, using pm2 to run the servers in the 'background' rather than blocking further commands in the terminal/cmd. I use configured a proxy inside my vue.config.js to redirect my API calls made in the frontend to the right base URL and used cors as middleware to allow requests to my API from other domains/ports.
2. Staging
   I use one script in a package.json to build the Vue app into a folder ('dist' folder inside my backend folder) that is a collection of static files and start the backend server. My backend is set up to know when I want to go into staging mode and then serve the static files in the 'dist' folder.
3. Production
   I use one script in a package.json to build the Vue app into a folder ('dist' folder inside my backend folder) that is a collection of static files and push my backend (incl. the built static files) to Heroku.

Comment: This is what Vue CLI proxy feature is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you need to run both on the same port you could first build your app so that you receive a dist directory or whatever your output directory is named and set up an express server that serves that app and otherwise handles your api requests

```
const express = require("express");

const path = __dirname + '/app/views/';
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path));

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

app.get('/api', function (req,res) {
  // your api handler
}

app.listen(8080)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
So you're saying res.sendFile the index.html and serve the static files in the 'views' folder of my Vue App. I tried. When I go to localhost:8080 it shows the index.html but it does not show any of the content that should be injected by Vue into the index.html. In other words the div with #app stays empty.
Also, in my index.html my title is set to: <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title> and when I try to serve the index.html it just gives my page the title <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>.

Comment: Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-express-server-forked-j9r4x?file=/index.js) example running a Vue app statically with express.

Comment: Ah @Estus Flask comment made me remember the proxy feature.
Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-express-server-forked-h9owi) using the proxy feature instead. This way you'll have to start 2 Dev-Servers but your Vue app requests can be proxied to your api without chaning your baseUrl in the Vue app itself.
It's up to you what you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This really pushed me in the right direction. I was looking for a prod and dev environment that are easy to work with. My application now runs on two ports in dev but I can start it up with one command -- also the prod server for staging and the deployment are one command. This article and video on vue in production also helped ([link](https://medium.com/@zhzhang.4390/vue-in-production-how-to-call-or-proxy-apis-f8045b5a7d16)).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that node and the 'app' will always run on the same server you can just use a template library like ejs.

You would then just bundle the app and api together, assuming that the front-end is tied to the backend, realistically you would not even need to hit the API as you could just return the  records as part of the view, however if dynamic elements are needed you could still hit the API.

Now, with that said, if the API is something used by many applications then it would probably make sense to build that out as its own microservice, running on its own server and your frontend would be on its own. This way you have separation of concerns with the API and Vue app.

Comment: Thanks. My app does have dynamic elements and my API is only called by my app. I am trying to set up a production and development environment that resemble each other closely. Since in production I have one root URL for both my app and the API, I would like the same for my development environment.